# Visual C++ - Cannot open text file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Simple program to open up a file and read it's contents. Then a test at the end to see if I did in fact get the information. Every time I run it it tells me that it cannot open the file. I will post the contents of SaleSlips below. Why isn't it opening the file? It is also attempting to delete the file every run as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct SaleSlip{
    char name[20];
    int prodID;
    double value;
};

void main(){

    fstream slips;
    SaleSlip sales[17];
    slips.open("SaleSlips.txt", ios::in);
    if(slips.eof()){
        cout << "Cannot open file - SaleSlips.txt"<< endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(2);
    }
    int i = 0;
    while(!slips.eof()){
        slips.getline(sales[i].name, ' ');
        slips >> sales[i].prodID;
        slips.ignore(5, ' ');
        slips >> sales[i].value;
        slips.ignore(80, ' ');
        i++;
    }
    cout << sales[1].value;
    slips.close();
    system("pause");
}

Eric   1 200000.00
Sookie 2    200.00
Sookie 4    200.50
```

Answer (score 3):

You're opening the stream in output mode by using `ios::out`.  Use `ios::in` to read from it.

You've got a lot of other issues, too.  IE:

-The `if(!slips.eof())` after the file open will always cause an exit unless the file is empty.
-In your while loop, you are (probably accidentally) attempting to write the prodID and value into the slips file using `<<`.  Use `>>` to read from a stream and `<<` to write to it.

Comment: Haha, Sadly, I tried that earlier and gave me some weird error. I tried it again and still not opening.yeah the condition was wrong I feel stupid now....

Comment: What error are you getting now?  I just noticed that you need to move the `cout << sales[i].name` into your while loop. Otherwise it will probably cause a crash as the SaleSlip at index i will not have a name value.

Comment: My gosh. Okay so I got it to "read" it, but now as soon as the command console opens it says the project.exe is no longer worker, and I changed that to 1 after I realized what it did. The system("pause") is just so I can see what is outputs, disregard it.

Comment: I think you've got some of your function calls wrong in the while loop according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/. Getline's second parameter needs to be a streamsize , and the character delimiter (space) is the third parameter. The ignore call has the arguments switched around: it's supposed to take streamsize first, then delimiter.

Comment: I debugged it (even though I never really learned how, I figured it out), debugging is useful as hell. I wished we learned it originally... thanks Egg

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

You're opening the file for output (writing)

```
slips.open("SaleSlips.txt", ios::out);
```

Use`ios::in` instead for input (reading)

```
slips.open("SaleSlips.txt", ios::in);
```

Next, you're immediately testing for `!eof()`, which is the wrong logic.

```
if(!slips.eof())
```

You *don't* want to be at `eof()` when opening the file for input. `eof()` is `end of file`. When first opening the file for input you want to be at the beginning of the file; being at `eof()` is a bad thing. Your code should error out if `eof()` is true, not if it's false:

```
if(slips.eof()) {
  // It's an error if we're starting at eof()
}
```